# Create new object outside vs inside a cycle

Tags: java, cycle

Is it

```
Object o;
for (...) {
  o = new Object();
...
}
```

really better than

```
for (...) {
Object o = new Object();
...
}
```

in terms of performance?

I read this on a computer science book some time ago, but I was wondering how the modern compilers (especially the java compiler) react to this two piece of codes. Are the first form optimized in some way to have the same performances of the second one?

Comment: Contrary to your title, neither piece of code creates a new object outside the loop. It's important to understand the difference between objects and variables.

Comment: Well, yes, of course. I think I was just typing too fast, but thanks for point it out.